# Compile Lua without automatic conversion between strings and numbers

Tags: c, lua, strong-typing

Lua is generally a [strongly-typed](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Strong_and_weak_typing) language, providing almost no implicit conversion between data types.

However, numbers and strings do get [automatically coerced in a few cases](http://www.lua.org/manual/5.2/manual.html#3.4.2):

> *Lua provides automatic conversion between string and number values at run time. Any arithmetic operation applied to a string tries to convert this string to a number, following the rules of the Lua lexer. (The string may have leading and trailing spaces and a sign.) Conversely, whenever a number is used where a string is expected, the number is converted to a string, in a reasonable format*

Thus:

```lua
local x,y,z = "3","8","11"
print(x+y,z)  --> 11   11
print(x+y==z) --> false
print(x>z)    --> true
```

I do not want this. How can I recompile the Lua interpreter to remove all automatic conversion?

I would prefer to have:

```lua
print(x+y)    --> error: attempt to perform arithmetic on a string value
print(x>1)    --> error: attempt to compare number with string
print(x..1)   --> error: attempt to concatenate a number value
```

Comment: Doable, but not out of the box. You'll have to edit the innards of Lua. Start at http://www.lua.org/source/5.2/lvm.c.html#luaV_tonumber.

Comment: You might want to "fix" cases like this, too: `print("one="..1)`

Comment: Is creating your own dialect of lua, subtly (and silently!) different from mainstream *really* worth it?

Comment: @vonbrand Well, we've already compiled with 32-bit numbers instead of 64-bit, which has its own subtle implications (e.g. `os.time()` does not increase every second). That was supported by compile-time flags, though.

Comment: Can you please explicitly state which output you'd want (for your respective examples)?

Comment: @nicolas.leblanc Edited to add the desired output.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The illustrious [LHF](https://stackoverflow.com/users/107090/lhf) has commented above that this is not possible out of the box, and requires editing the innards of Lua, starting with http://www.lua.org/source/5.2/lvm.c.html#luaV_tonumber

Marking this as the answer in order to close this question. If anyone later chooses to provide an answer with in-depth details on what needs to be done, I will gladly switch the acceptance mark to that answer.

Comment: Agree, parameters get evaluated before being passed to the function, in this case "print". Hence the inner functioning of expression evaluation (IE coercion) needs to be changed.